# Checking if a singly linked list is empty c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, singly-linked-list

I am trying to figure out what the best and simplest way is of determining if a singly linked list is empty or not.

Would I need to create a boolean method?

Thanks

Read Method

void List::Read(istream& r)
{

```
char c[13];
r >> c;
r >> numberOfInts;

Node *node = new Node();

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfInts; i++)
{
    r >> node->data;
    cout << node->data << endl;
    node->next = new Node;
    //node = node->next;

    head = node;
}
}
else
{
    if(node->data > head->data)
    {
        head->next;
    }
    else if(node->data < head->data)
    {
        Node* tempNode;
        tempNode = head;
        head->data = node->data;
        node->data = tempNode->data;
    }
}
system("pause");
```

}

Header file

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node() {}
    Node(int d, Node* q = 0) : data(d), next(q) {} //constructor with parameters data and next
    int data; //holds data in node
    Node* next;//pointer to next node
};

class List
{
public:
    void Read(istream&);
    void Write(ostream&);

    void setReadSort(bool);
    void sortOwn();
    void insertionSort(Node*);
    bool isEmpty();

    bool _sortRead;
    int numberOfInts;

    List(void);
    ~List(void);
protected:
    Node *head;
    Node current;
};
```

Comment: sorry if you need more information

Comment: 'List' should not have a 'current' data member, since the "current" node only makes sense in the context of performing some operation upon the list - by definition, it is temporary, not a part of the data model.

Answer (score 2):

This completely depends on the implementation.  However, this typically can be done very quickly by checking to see if the first node exists/has contents/etc.

Comment: the first node always exists and if it doesnt have anything read into it then whats read in is the memory address -8etc...

Comment: @Tazzy: If the first node always exists, it probably "stores" the data in a pointer or similar.  Just check to see if the pointer is NULL.

Comment: @Tazzy: You'll need to give us more information if you want us to help.  Unless we know how things are stored, and in what format, we can't really tell you how to check this

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The reason is: sometimes we use the iterator to insert element, it would be very uncomfortable (or impossible) to handle the number of the elements over the iterators. This is the reason why many STL implementation has linear time for `size_t size(void)` function. `bool empty(void)` is an effective way to check if the list is empty and it has constant time.

Just to note: when you use STL prefer to use `bool empty(void)` against `size_t size(void)`. More info in: [Meyers: Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629).

The function is simple:

```
bool empty( void ) const
{
  return ( this->begin() == this->end() );
}
```

In your case:

```
bool empty( void ) const
{
  return ( this->head == 0 );
}
```

Comment: i dont need to put the == 0 cos without that is says its empty

Comment: I always write out `== 0`, because it is easier to read for me. Of course: you could use it without the `== 0`, too.

Comment: @Tazzy: keep `== 0` or use `bool(this->head)`. ;)

Comment: no not that either, am I using it wrong maybe? that wouldnt surprise me, im very new to this

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but it should work.

[edit] Changed program to account for a head that always exists.

[edit] Changed program to account for class, instead of a struct

```
bool isEmpty(){return (this->head == NULL)};
```

This will give a more proper result

One more thing, I see that you are using system("pause");. I know that this is homework, but that is extremely bad practice. A better method would be to first clear the buffer in stdin (if needed), then ignore a character. An example would be:

```
cin >> somenumber; // Extract a number (assuming its safe)
cin.ignore(1, 10); // Ignore 1 character, or a newline, whichever comes first
                   // ^ this clears the buffer, it does NOT wait for input since
                   // the formatted extraction left a character in the buffer ('\n')
cin.ignore();      // Essentially the same as above, but since there is nothing in
                   // the buffer, it reads a single character from stdin
```

Comment: the isEmpty method breaks apparently

Comment: wasnt me, i havent voted yet, dont even know how to down vote

Comment: @Tazzy It works, as long as you make it a class method. this->head == NULL will return true only if there is no head. If you want to always have a head, then you will change it to this->head->next == NULL, to check if the head has a node that it points to.